# What is the default date style used by an instance of SQL Server when converting from varchar to datetime?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion, varchar

I've run this SQL query on two different servers:

```
declare @test as datetime='2020-05-06 00:00:00'
select Convert (nvarchar,@test)
```

The results were different on the two servers:

1. May  6 2020 12:00AM
2. Jun  5 2020 12:00AM

I know the reason behind this, when SQL Server is reading the string that I passed `2020-05-06 00:00:00` and converting it to `DateTime` in the declare statement, it's using the default date style.

Am I able to configure this default style, or in other words, how is default date style chosen in SQL Server when converting the `varchar` to `datetime`? Is it from the windows regional settings or some other configurations inside SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses a style based on the language. Basically, for the date above, if you're American then the date will be read as `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`, however, if use over languages, then it's be (stupidly) read as `yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss`.

If you are using strings for dates (like your literal here) then aim to use an unambiguous format. In SQL Server, regardless of data type and language, those are `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn` and `yyyyMMdd`.

If you're convert to an `(n)varchar`, always use a [style code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles) (and a length for your `varchar`) for consistent results.

So, for your value, you can run the below to find out what the default conversion value would be for all the languages on your instance:

```
DECLARE Languages CURSOR FOR
SELECT alias
FROM sys.syslanguages;

DECLARE @Alias sysname,
        @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

CREATE TABLE #ConvertedDates (Alias sysname, dt datetime, converted nvarchar(25));

DECLARE @dt datetime = '2020-05-06T00:00:00'

OPEN Languages

FETCH NEXT FROM Languages
INTO @Alias;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @SQL = N'SET LANGUAGE ' + QUOTENAME(@Alias) + N'; INSERT INTO #ConvertedDates(Alias,dt,converted) VALUES(N' + QUOTENAME(@Alias,'''') + ',@dt,CONVERT(nvarchar(25),@dt));';

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@dt datetime', @dt;

    FETCH NEXT FROM Languages
    INTO @Alias;

END;

CLOSE Languages;
DEALLOCATE Languages;

SELECT *
FROM #ConvertedDates;

DROP TABLE #ConvertedDates;
```

*Yes, that is a Cursor. I wanted to ensure that each dynamic statement ran by itself, to ensure language was preserved for each conversion.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I am aware of the style codes that I can use to convert a date to (n)varchar, I use this usually. I was just surprised by the default behavior of SQL Server when it's converting it itself from varchar to date. The actual code is sending the date as a parameter to a stored procedure, that's why "I think" we don't have full control of the format. Based on your answer, I guess by language that you mean the language used while installing? Or the installer itself?

Comment: No, the language of the `LOGIN`, @PaulKaram .